# Is it a crime to remove someone's mask?

Tags: criminal-law

During a protest or just on the street in a one off incident (not necessarily a crime), if someone is wearing a mask to hide their identity, and someone else (both citizens, not police etc) reaches forward and gently pulls down or removes their mask/scarf etc., would that be some form of crime? E.g. assault or battery?

Comment: The jurisdiction would matter. For example, in New York State it is illegal to wear a mask that conceals your identity in public, but this is not illegal in Colorado. The legality of wearing a mask influences the legality of removing it. Also particular criminal assault statutes have slight differences in wording that matter in de minimis cases like this one.

Comment: @ohwilleke to be explicit, are you saying that generally if it is legal to wear one, it would be illegal to remove it?

Comment: "are you saying that generally if it is legal to wear one, it would be illegal to remove it?" No. I'm saying that would be one factor in addition to the language of the relevant criminal statutes (both offenses and general justification principles), that would have to be considered to determine if it was legal. All of those laws can differ from one place to another.

Answer (score 2):

### United States

It varies by the jurisdiction. Under [New York law](https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/PEN/120.00), you could commit the crime of 3rd degree assault if you caused injury, but otherwise there doesn't seem to be any offense. Under [Idaho law](https://legislature.idaho.gov/statutesrules/idstat/Title18/T18CH9/SECT18-903/), you have committed the crime of battery, punishable by a fine of $1000 and 6 months in county jail.